# How to show one-to-two relationship in entity diagrams?

Tags: relational-database, entity-relationship, diagram

I have a table called "Transaction" that takes place between two instances of "User" table. Now, in the entity diagram, how can I show one-to-two relationship between "Transaction" and "User" tables?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Label the edge with [1..2] or [0..2] or whatever fits your case.